# Mongoose query returning empty array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Below is my express endpoint that returns an empty array

```
router.get('/myUnits/:landlord_id', wagner.invoke((Apartment) => {
    return (req, res) => {
      Apartment.find({ postedBy: req.params.landlord_id }, (err, apt) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .json({ error: err.toString() })
        }
        if (!apt) {
          return res.status(status.NOT_FOUND)
                    .json({ error: 'Not found' })
        }
        return res.json(apt)
      })
    }
  }))
```

I changed `Apartment.find({ price: 200 })` and it queries all data with the `price: 200` but querying for `postedBy` does not work at all.

When I go to my mongo shell and do a query

```
db.apartments.find({ postedBy: 'the id of the account here' })
```

it returns the appropriate data.

[image: https://gyazo.com/77afa64f9afb75f47667d0f47757c3e4]

Comment: add console.log(req.params.landlord_id) above Apartment.find. What is the output? If that's the id you expect then try to remove `postedBy: req.params.landlord_id` from `Apartment.find({...` now it should return everything from db. Does it?

Comment: @Molda thank you for the immediate reply. Yes, it returns everything from my db but I only want it to return data specific to the landlord. How do I do that?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure everything works correctly. you didn't answer my first question tho, What is the output of console.log(req.params.landlord_id) placed above Apartment.find ? Otherwise your code looks ok i can't see any problem

Comment: The output is 56e1ec5d4635a55403900d78. When I use this id in the mongo shell I get what I query for.

Comment: Ok you might want to try to cast the id to ObjectId like : `postedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.landlord_id)`

Comment: Could work, but the shell result would probably has `"postedBy": ObjectId("...")` instead of just the string. Have you try `console.log(apt)` just before returning it (I don't have lots of hope here...). Maybe try `mongoose.set('debug', true)`.

Comment: @Cohars console.log(apt) returns an empty array.

Comment: @Cohars, I tried to debug and this is what I got 
`Mongoose: apartments.find({ postedBy: ObjectId("56e20f228d4f3e9e0566df58") }) { fields: undefined }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was in my schema all along.

```
let apartmentSchema = {
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  promotion: { type: String, required: true },
  postedOn: { type: Date, required: true },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // this was the culprit
    required: true
  }
}
```

I just changed the type to String. I used the ObjectId from a previous api that I long since updated. Thank you for your patience guys!

Comment: Ok, it could also be a string actually. But you should add a ref: `postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }`